# How to use my Samsung Captivate as a device for debugging?

Tags: android, mobile-phones, mobile-devices

I am following the steps listed here: http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/device.html.

I'm using eclipse 3.6 (It was the only download i could find... couldn't find 3.5). When i run SDK Manager.exe I see that I have USB Driver Packer, Revision 3 installed.

I Set my phone to enable USB Debugging and I plug in my phone to my computer's USB jack.

At this point, I do not see the device in eclipse debug configuration. Should I? Am I missing something?

Comment: Yes it should show up in your devices list.

Comment: The question is what i should troubleshoot because it doesn't

Comment: Get 3.5 : http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/release/galileo/sr2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that all Android phones are not supported by the driver package. For instance, I recently discovered that I had to download HTC sync to be able to debug on a HTC Desire.
So I think this might be pretty much the same for samsung ...
Did you install Samsung PC Studio?

If this is not enough, you can have a look at [this page](http://adrianvintu.com/blogengine/post/How-to-Debug-on-the-Samsung-Galaxy-I7500-Android-Phone.aspx). It's actually about samsung galaxy, but it should be quite similar...

Comment: I have HTC phones and even if I don't have HTC Sync on the PC the debugging works when connected and usb debug is enabled.